# Error with julia's code_native function

Tags: scientific-computing, julia

I'm trying out Julia and stumbled upon the nifty "code_native" function. Unfortunately, it doesn't work here:

```
julia> affine(x) = 2*x + 3
affine (generic function with 1 method)

julia> affine(3)
9

julia> typeof(3)
Int64

julia> code_native(affine,(Int64,))
Warning: Unable to find function pointer
ERROR: no method found for the specified argument types
```

What's wrong? I'm using the default interactive interpreter with the julia package on Arch linux.

Comment: That's bizarre... Works fine on Windows and Ubuntu. Did you build from scratch or use a package installer?

Comment: I get the same thing in OS X on julia built from Homebrew, but it works fine on julia built from the git repository (also on OS X).

Comment: May be worth opening an issue (I can't reproduce but I always compile from source).

Comment: Likewise works for me using 0.2.1 on both Ubuntu and OS/X installed from binary packages.  Are you using by chance using Arch Linux ARM?  What happens when you call code_llvm(affine,(Int64,))?

Comment: I'm using stock x86_64 Arch, did not recompile anything.

Comment: Please do open an issue. (might be an LLVM version issue, I thought someone said Arch is on 3.4, which we don't actively test)

Comment: @Isaiah, you may be on to something. I forgot to mention that the Homebrew version I have is compiled with the --HEAD option.  This causes it to use LLVM version 3.4.

Comment: I have x86_64 Arch and I use downgraded 3.3 LLVM package since 3.4 just gives random failures. This is an option if one doesn't need 3.4 for something else and don't want to wait Julia LLVM compilation (that's me).

Comment: I've just read through Julia Arch package comments and it seems that LLVM 3.4 compatibility may have in fact been fixed. Later, I'll try again with 3.4.

Comment: `code_native` seems to be working ok with master Julia in my machine x86_64 Arch, compiled with `USE_SYSTEM_LLVM=1` (LLVM 3.4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely an issue with using LLVM 3.4.  Note that the Homebrew builds [recently switched](https://github.com/staticfloat/homebrew-julia/commit/e2cd04cddfa75bdbbd2cf03469158ca6f6bc31a5) to using LLVM 3.3 (instead of the Homebrew default of 3.4), as LLVM 3.4 compatibility isn't support yet in Julia.

Comment: There's currently a [patch in progress](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/6737) to fix this issue, too.

Comment: I can confirm that it works on my system now. Still using the stock Arch Linux version.